# How to get addElement value in to variable?

Tags: php, moodle, quickform

is there any option in moodle php to take `username` value in to variable ?

I just wanna take **username** in to `$myUser` when the form loading.

```
$mform->addElement('text', 'username', get_string('forumname', 'forum'), $attributes);
```

Reference:- http://docs.moodle.org/dev/lib/formslib.php_Form_Definition#addElement

Comment: What do you need to do with $myuser once you have it?

Comment: @Russell England I need that value for `onkeyup($myUser);` javaScript.

Comment: I'm guessing you should probably use a YUI module with your form - http://docs.moodle.org/dev/YUI/Modules

Answer (score 1):

From outside of your form:

```
$form = new my_form();
$currentdata = (object)array('username' => $user->username);
$form->set_data($currentdata);
```

In rare cases where this isn't possible, you can, instead, use customdata to pass it in:

```
$form = new my_form(null, array('username' => $user->username));
```

Then, within your form:

```
$username = $this->_customdata['username'];
$mform->addElement('text', 'username', get_string('forumname', 'forum'), $attributes);
$mform->setDefault('username', $username);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what to suggest, I use moodle forms every day and what I have described above has always worked for me. Maybe if you post more of the code, either here or on moodle.org, then someone could point out where you are going wrong.